# IKVM load jars from .NET project

Tags: ikvm

Is there any way to load a jar file from .NET project using IKVM?

Summary of what I am trying to achieve
1) I have a .NET project that uses a Java code (MYClass) compiled to a .NET DLL using IKVM.
2) MyClass function F1() uses a class present in say Try.jar.
3) When I make a call to Function F1() from .NET code, it throws an exception related to Try.jar

My question is it possible to load Try.jar in .Net project.
I dont want to compile Try.jar as a DLL using ikvmc.

Comment: I was able to load the jar by adding the jar to class path using System.setProperty("java.lang.path",""); Although dynamically loaded jar runs very slowly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want load a jar file then you need to implements a `URLClassLoader`. See in the [IKVM wiki](https://sourceforge.net/p/ikvm/wiki/Run_a_jar_file_on_the_fly/) for details.

Comment: I tried to add my custom URLClassLoader but I am getting an error for ikvm.runtime.AssemblyClassLoader. In which assembly can i find this class

Comment: With ILSpy you can look in every assembly dll. ikvm.runtime.AssemblyClassLoader can you find in IKVM.OpenJDK.Core.dll.